# looping through tagged products to show them in the additional detail box in the Shopify backend

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to loop through tagged products to show in the the additional detail box in the backend, but I only get one product. Here is the case, I have some products tagged with warranty, so I'm implementing a condition stating that if the customers cart has - say - 3 products (2 of those tagged with warranty and the other one is not), then I would like to bring the names of the ones tagged with warranty and display them in the additional detail box in the backend.

The issue I'm facing is that I get only one product name even if the customer's order included 3 different products with the same warranty tag.

This is the code I'm implementing:

```
 {% for itemTwo in cart.items %}

<p class="cart-attribute__field">
      {% for tag in itemTwo.product.tags %}
      {% if tag contains 'warranty' %}

  <input id="products-registered" type="text" name="attributes[products registered]" value="{{ itemTwo.product.title }}">

        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

  </p>

        {% endfor %}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around. I had to loop over the value in the input field. That solved out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`name=attributes[products registered]` should to be unique.  Try including `{{ forloop.index}}` in there:

```
{% for itemTwo in cart.items %}
  <p class="cart-attribute__field">
    {% for tag in itemTwo.product.tags %}
      {% if tag contains 'warranty' %}
        <input id="products-registered" type="text" name="attributes[product registered {{forloop.index}}]" value="{{ itemTwo.product.title }}">
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </p>
{% endfor %}
```

**Edit:**
On second thoughts, `foorloop.index` will return the index of the tag forloop not the itemTwo forloop, so that's not going to be reliable, might be better to include the [line item key](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/line_item#line_item-key) in there.